# BitConverter uchar?

Tags: c#

How do I convert an array of bytes to an unsigned char (0 to 255, not -127 to 127)

If I'm not mistaken `BitConverter` only has `BitConverter.ToChar` which doesn't give me the result I'm looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: @DanielA.White Nah, what is called a `System.Char` in .NET is a UTF-16 code unit which consists of sixteen bits. It may be a lower or upper part of a surrogate pair, of course, or it may code a combining character. But a `Char` in .NET is not 8 bits.

Comment: What are the types you ask for? Signed 8-bit integers are called `sbyte` in C# (`System.SByte` in the framework). Unsigned 8-bit integers are called `byte` (`System.Byte`). You say char, but in C# the keyword `char` is used for a UTF-16 code unit whose range is from `0` to `65535`.

Answer (score 1):

An array of bytes (`byte[]`) is already an array of items that are 0 to 255. `char`s in .NET are multibyte because they are Unicode. There's no such thing as a `uchar` in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your usage. `BitConverter.ToChar` [is used to convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tochar(v=vs.110).aspx) 2 bytes from your byte array to an Unicode character (think of that as deserialization). In .NET, the `char` [data type is used to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx) represent an actual Unicode character, so it contains 2 bytes.

If your goal is to simply get an array of integers between 0 and 255, your byte array is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the byte array to string

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

or cast/convert them to `char`:

```
char[] chars = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, Convert.ToChar);
```

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII` is useful if all the bytes are in the range `0` through `127`. Otherwise, choose a "codepage" such as `string str = (new System.Text.Encoding("Windows-1252")).GetString(bytes);`.